# Mapbox not loading map on netlify

Tags: mapbox, gatsby, netlify

I have a mapbox project, built in gatsby.
I am hosting it on Netlify.
It works locally, but not when on netlify.

https://unruffled-lichterman-25e46c.netlify.app/
Click Explore.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same issue. Did this ever get resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Look at your browser's console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: m is not defined
```

My guess is that you are missing the environment variables in Netlify side. When dealing with [Gatsby + Netlify](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/common-configurations/gatsby/#gatsby-build-plugin) you need to prefix all environment variables with `GATSBY_`:

> Any [environment variables](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/environment-variables) prefixed with `GATSBY_` are processed by
> Gatsby and made available in the browser for client-side JavaScript
> access. Visit the [Gatsby docs about environment variables](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/) for more
> information.

So, add them as well as locally and in Netlify's dashboard, it will be at: https://app.netlify.com/sites/YOUR_SITE_NAME/settings/deploys#environment

[image]

Remember to change the references in your code too.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you need a proper config in `webpack.config.js`.

You can also configure worker-loader centrally in `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\bmapbox-gl-csp-worker.js\b/i,
                use: { loader: 'worker-loader' }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

For further details, please refer to the [documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/guides/install/#transpiling)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I tried to add the webpack configuration but it didn't work for me. At the end try adding the symbol ! on import like this:

```js
import mapboxgl from '!mapbox-gl'; // eslint-disable-line import/no-webpack-loader-syntax
```

and that worked